# ASP.NET MVC Child ViewModel validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Working with ViewModels, I would like to split them:

```
public SignUpViewModel //for display
{
   public SignUpUserViewModel SignUpUserViewModel { get; set; } //for validation
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserTypes {get;set;}
}
```

So I want to render SignUpViewModel but get SignUpUserViewModel as an argument of POST-action.

Do you find this reasonable? What are the ways to implement this approach?

Looks like DefaultModelBinder doesn't work this way: it doens't understand SignUpUserViewModel is a property of SignUpViewModel. So one way I see is to implement custom model binder. Any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's reasonable. Just have your post action bind to the `SignUpUserViewModel`.

E.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, SignUpUserViewModel editForm)
```

On a side note, looking at your `SignUpViewModel` vs `SignUpUserViewModel`, I think you could just combine them into the one view model.

In saying that I will say that I too sometimes have a similar setup to what you have, e.g. `ViewModel` and a child `FormModel` (posting and binding to the `FormModel`) **but** I put anything to do with the form like validation and  the SelectListItems in the `FormModel`. So in your case above, I would just combine them into the one FormModel.